# If parent category is checked, don't echo children category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this Continent -> Country category setup for a custom post type.

```
- Africa (parent 1)
    - Uganda
    - Zambia
    - Zimbabwe
- Asia (parent 2)
    - Afghanistan
    - Bahrain
    - Bangladesh
    - Bhutan
```

If parent category is checked for a post, don't echo the children categories. (even if one or more children is checked) `echo => Africa, Asia`

*And the revert,* if one or more child categories is checked, but the parent category is **NOT** checked. Show only the child categories. `echo => Uganda, Zambia, Zimbabwe, Afghanistan, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Bhutan`

**UPDATE** 
Also if Africa (parent 1) is checked, while Asia (parent 2) is **NOT** checke, but Afghanistan and Bhutan (children of parent 2) is checked the output should be: `echo => Africa, Afghanistan, Bhutan.`

This will only output **IF** there is one or more parent categories checked.

```
<?php

$post = get_post(); // If $post is already available, skip.
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom-category' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
    if ( $term->parent === 0 ) :
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'custom-category' ) ) . 
            '" title="' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . esc_html( $term->name ) . 
            '</a> ';
    endif;
endforeach;

    ?>
```

How to output the child catergories if their parent is **NOT** checked?

Comment: Hi. May I ask you to post the code you've already written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to figure out a solution to this problem! This is tested and produces my desired result! If you have a more elegant solution, please let me know!

```
    <?php

    $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom-category' );

    // If term is a parent, add to post_parent array.
    $post_parent = array();
    foreach( $categories as $parent_id ) {
        if($parent_id->parent < 1) {
            $post_parent[] = $parent_id->term_id;
        }
    }

    // If terms parentId does not exist in post_parent array
    // add to array regions as a key => value pair
    $regions = array();
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        if (!in_array($category->parent, $post_parent)) {
            $regions[$category->term_id] = $category->name;
        }
    }

    // Sort terms based on keys (regions), impolde and print
    ksort($regions);
    $locations = array();
    foreach($regions as $key => $value) {
      $locations[] = ' <a href="https://www.google.com/maps?q=' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>';
    }

    echo implode(",", $locations);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code which help you for logic of the need you may modify it for your output requirements

```
$post = get_post(); // If $post is already available, skip.
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );    
$outputparent = $outputchild = array();
foreach( $terms as $term ) :
    if( $term->parent === 0 ) :
        $outputparent[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . 
            '" title="' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . esc_html( $term->name ) . 
            '</a> ';            
    else :
        $outputchild[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . 
            '" title="' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . esc_html( $term->name ) . 
            '</a>';
    endif; //Endif
endforeach;

if( !empty( $outputparent ) ) :
    echo 'Parent category is checked<br>';
    echo implode('<br>', $outputparent);
    $outputchild = array();
elseif( !empty( $outputchild ) && empty( $outputparent ) ) :
    echo 'Only Childs<br>';
    echo implode('<br>', $outputchild); 
endif;
```

Comment: Now only the parents (Africa and Asia) is beeing outputed, no child (countries) is beeing outpted even if their parents are **NOT** checked. I forgot to mention that if Africa is checked, while Asia is **NOT** checke, but Afghanistan and Bhutan is checked the output should be: `=> Africa, Afghanistan, Bhutan.` (I'll update the question)

Comment: See When I choose like this - http://prntscr.com/qyfnuo It will print - Africa, Asia 
When I choose like this - http://prntscr.com/qyfowl - It will print - Bahrain, Bangladesh, Bhutan, Zimbabwe, Zambia

Comment: You are right, but this code does not let you mix those two. I am sorry, I forgot to mention!

Comment: Okay need to think on it and work on it to achieve exactly the same